# Taxonomy Term View with Expose filter Dropdown of Terms Name

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I Have a view of Taxonomy and "not Content".
In this View I want a Expose filter of Term Name. But when ever i add Term Name as expose taxonomy's filter it shows text box and not Dropdown.

Without using relationship with content is it possible to get Dropdown filter of term's name as expose filter in Drupal 8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get a dropdown filter you dont have to choose the taxonomy name rather the taxonomy term and select the vacabulary.

You follow this steps to get what you need :

1- https://monosnap.com/direct/Zw1q6Ww9If5vQZAAQsvysCt3TmL4L7

2- https://monosnap.com/direct/P4YbmYcXooNk7eLd1kev5y9sRyxekW

3- https://monosnap.com/direct/7gI69kySC5ciKtaBeBtbRRkCQS9Mf1)

Comment: Thanks. It was right in-front of me but somehow i missed it. ;-)